# Showing an Ideal is Irreducible (alternative proof)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Recently, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1276144/showing-an-ideal-is-irreducible) was posted regarding the following:

> **Question:** Show $$(x^3,y^5,z^2)\subset\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$$ is an irreducible ideal.

I was wondering if the following could be reviewed and, if flawed, a proof in a similar direction could be achieved.

**Attempt:** Observe $\sqrt{(x^3,y^5,z^2)}=\sqrt{(x,y,z)}=(x,y,z)$ is prime as $$\frac{\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]}{(x^3,y^5,z^2)}}{\frac{(x,y,z)}{(x^3,y^5,z^2)}}\cong\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]}{(x,y,z)}\cong\mathbb{C}$$
So $Spec\bigg(\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]}{(x^3, y^5, z^2)}\bigg)$
is irreducible and therefore $(x^3,y^5,z^2)$ is irreducible.

Comment: @MichaelBurr : See the definition and this Wikipedia page. There is an issue ; Ideals inducing an irreducible affine scheme do not necessarily come from an irreducible ideal. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_ideal

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva So it "could" be irreducible. Is there any way to bridge the gap? I was hoping for a much shorter proof.

Comment: Suppose $(x^3, y^5, z^2) = \mathfrak a \cap \mathfrak b$ for $\mathfrak a, \mathfrak b$ two ideals strictly between $(x^3,y^5,z^2)$ and $\mathbb C[x,y,z]$. Then $\sqrt{(x^3,y^5,z^2)} \subseteq \sqrt{\mathfrak a}, \sqrt{\mathfrak b}$, hence we have equality there since $\sqrt{(x^3,y^5,z^2)} = (x,y,z)$ is maximal.  This is as far as I got using only geometric ideas. I only said there was an issue with the proof, the statement is right ; there is a proof of different flavor in the OP's link.